# GitLab CI CD runner not loading properties file for profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I run a command `mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=GITLAB-CI-TEST` in the GitLab CI CD it not loading properties file `application-gitlab-ci-test.properties`. It is loading only `application.properties`.

As file `application-gitlab-ci-test.properties` contains the different value for `spring.datasource.url`  the pipeline is failing in the remote runners with error

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Of course, this error is expected as properties file `application.properties` refers to the localhost database.

Code which loading `application-gitlab-ci-test.properties`:

```java
@Profile("GITLAB-CI-TEST")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-gitlab-ci-test.properties")
@Configuration
public class GitLabCiTestProfile {
}
```

When I try to run the same command locally it's working as expected and in logs, I see the following records:

> 2020-03-30 19:23:00.609 DEBUG 604 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file
>   'file:/G:/****/****/****/****/target/classes/application.properties'
>   (classpath:/application.properties)
>
> 2020-03-30 19:23:00.609 DEBUG 604 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file
>   'file:/G:/****/****/****/****/target/classes/application-GITLAB-CI-TEST.properties' (classpath:/application-GITLAB-CI-TEST.properties) for profile
>   GITLAB-CI-TEST

I noticed that remote runners missing the second line. This one which loading `application-GITLAB-CI-TEST.properties`.

I also tried `mvn clean test --batch-mode -PGITLAB-CI-TEST` and this one too failing in the remote host but in local run working as expected.

I found the workaround for this issue by using the command

```
mvn clean test --batch-mode -Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/*******?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue as this workaround is not satisfying me?

Comment: I'm not an expert with maven and spring but : where your `application-GITLAB-CI-TEST.properties` is located ? Is this location part of the classpath during the runner execution ? Also, could you try using this flag (without `spring.profiles.active`) : `--spring.config.location=file:///path/to/your/file`

Comment: I checked and `application-gitlab-ci-test.properties` for sure part of the classpath.
This is the part of result of build:
$ cd target/classes
 $ ls -la
 total 40
 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Mar 29 22:37 .
 drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root 4096 Mar 29 22:38 ..
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  861 Mar 29 22:37 application-gitlab-ci-test.properties
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  887 Mar 29 22:37 application.properties
 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Mar 29 22:37 pl

Comment: I just thought that this issue might be caused by java version. For the local build, I'm using java 13. On the remote runners, I'm using java 14. I will verify it tomorrow.

Comment: Could you add the "part of result of build" in your question ? Could you also print value of `CLASSPATH` variable ? And did you try with `spring.config.location` arg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue.
I changed the name of the profile from the upper case (`GITLAB-CI-TEST`) to lower case (`gitlab-ci-test`), to match the lower case of profile name in properties file - `application-gitlab-ci-test.properties`.

Now in the remote runner, I'm using the following command:

`mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=gitlab-ci-test`

Spring doc - [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)